# How to set Red Color in Camera.Parameters.setColorEffect

Tags: android, video-capture

Is it possible to set *Red, Green Color* Overlay in `Camera.Parameters.setColorEffect`?? and How??
I am seeing only following effects.

```
EFFECT_MONO
EFFECT_AQUA
```

etc.

But I want to put some color like RED, Green etc.

Comment: use `Camera.getParameters().getSupportedColorEffects()` to get list of all supported effects and check RED is available or not before setting

Comment: As i said i checked red is not supported only `[none, mono, negative, sepia]` are available. my question is can i create effect?? Or can I put some Indicator on Video.